# Wired Internet only works for seconds after connecting

Tags: networking, 16.04, internet, dns, ethernet

I've recently installed 16.04 to my desktop. After experiencing this problem for days I've reinstalled cleanly multiple times.

Upon logging in I am able to browse the internet for about 30 seconds, after that, it stops working and I get a "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_BAD_CONFIG" message. If I access the 'Ethernet Network' icon in the upper right in GNOME and click "Wired connection 1" it seems to work for a few more seconds, then stops working again.

The whole time my ethernet shows as connected.

I'm able to ping 8.8.8.8 if the internet is working or not, but I am *not able* to ping google.com when the internet isn't working.

I get that this is a DNS problem, but I don't know where to go from here.

Any help would be muhc appreciated.

Comment: It suggests a problem at the router more than anything else. Assuming you already rule out the obvious, i.e., the cable.

Comment: It could also be `network-manager`.

Comment: I have reset the router and modem already. The internet works fine on macOS (different machine) and on my windows partition with the problem.